# Unable to programatically reference subreport property (EnableExternalImages) from main report

Tags: reportviewer, rdlc, subreport

I have what i think is a unique requirement not addressed in other questions. I've developed a  local report in Microsoft report designer as an rdlc and am viewing it via the report viewer control. The report contains a subreport. The subreport renders images from external files. The problem is that i need to programmatically set the EnableExternalImages property of the subreport at run time. Without this, the subreport refuses to render ("Error: Subreport could not be shown" is the error message i get). I've set this property on the main/outer report programatically without issue using this statement:

Me.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.EnableExternalImages = True

However i need to do the same on the sub-report...so optimally, i would like to code something like this:

Me.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Subreport1.EnableExternalImages = True.

Problem is, i don't see a property available that provides me direct access to the subreport's properties in this fashion. I've looked into using the SubreportProcessingEvent, however this event only exposes a limited number of properties of the sub-report (Reportparamaters, Datasources, ReportPath, etc..), but does not provide me with access to all of it's properties (e.g. EnableExternalImages property).

Thanks for any information...

Comment: i'm having exatcly the same issue, did you find any solution ?

Comment: Have you tried the SubreportProcessing event? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.winforms.localreport.subreportprocessing.aspx